# How to find the arities of a clojurescript function?

Tags: clojurescript

Is there a way to get the arities of a cljs function? In java, there is reflect but I don't know how to do it here:
for example:

```
(defn add
  ([]
  ([n] n)
  ([n m] (+ n m))

(arities add) => [0 1 2]
```

I know that you can use `(.-length f)` to return the maximum length, but how would all of them be returned?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this at runtime and it's unlikely to get added in the future. You can access some of this information via macros, or through the ClojureScript analyzer/compiler directly.